# Lightroom: Changing text color in Preferences -> Lightroom Sync

Tags: lightroom, sync, settings

Adobe Lightroom is reporting a sync error, but cannot read the details in Preferences -> Lightroom Sync as it is blue text on gray background. Does anyone know how to change to a better text color?

[image]